# High CPU usage in Custom JPasswordField

Tags: java, swing, jpasswordfield

I have created a **custom PasswordField extending JPasswordField**. And It is working fine. But the problem is when I use this passwordfield and run the JFrame, this consumes HIGH CPU Usage. I only add this component and run it. But when I use another component like JButton or TextField It works fine and CPU usage is normal. So I need to know how to fix that problem or whether there is a problem in my code that eats CPU. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

**Here is the code,**

```
public class PasswordField extends JPasswordField implements ComponentListener
{
    private boolean materialMode = false;
    private Color borderColorNoFocus = MaterialColor.GREY_300;
    private Color borderColorFocus = new Color(0, 112, 192);
    private Dimension d = new Dimension(250, 42);
    private String placeholder = "";
    private Color phColor = new Color(0, 112, 192);
    private boolean band = true;
    private final JButton button = new JButton();
    private ImageIcon iconBlack = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Library/Images/visibleBlack.png"));
    private ImageIcon iconWhite = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Library/Images/visibleWhite.png"));
    private boolean xBlackIcon = false;
    private int btnHeight = this.d.height - 10;
    private boolean txtVisible = false;

    public PasswordField()
    {
        this.setEchoChar('*');
        this.setSize(this.d);
        this.setPreferredSize(this.d);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setMargin(new Insets(3, 6, 3, 6));

        this.setFont(Roboto.BOLD.deriveFont(14.0F));
        this.setForeground(new Color(0, 112, 192));
        this.button.setText("");
        this.button.setBorderPainted(false);
        this.button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        this.button.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
        this.button.setVisible(true);
        this.button.setFocusPainted(false);
        this.button.setCursor(new Cursor(12));
        this.button.setBackground(new Color(0, 112, 192));
        this.add(this.button);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.addComponentListener(this);
        this.setSelectionColor(this.button.getBackground());
        updateButton();

        this.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
            {
                PasswordField.this.band = (PasswordField.this.getText().length() <= 0);
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
            {
                PasswordField.this.band = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {}
        });

        this.button.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if (PasswordField.this.txtVisible)
                {
                    ((JPasswordField)PasswordField.this.button.getParent()).setEchoChar('*');
                    PasswordField.this.iconBlack = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Library/Images/visibleBlack.png"));
                    PasswordField.this.iconWhite = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Library/Images/visibleWhite.png"));
                    PasswordField.this.txtVisible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    ((JPasswordField)PasswordField.this.button.getParent()).setEchoChar('\000');
                    PasswordField.this.iconBlack = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Library/Images/invisibleBlack.png"));
                    PasswordField.this.iconWhite = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Library/Images/invisibleWhite.png"));
                    PasswordField.this.txtVisible = true;
                }
        ((JPasswordField)PasswordField.this.button.getParent()).requestFocus();
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
            {
                PasswordField.this.button.setOpaque(true);
                PasswordField.this.button.setIcon(PasswordField.this.xBlackIcon ? PasswordField.this.iconBlack : PasswordField.this.iconWhite);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
            {
                PasswordField.this.button.setOpaque(false);
                PasswordField.this.button.setIcon(null);
            }
        });
        this.setPlaceholder("Password Field");
    }

    public boolean isxDarkIcon()
    {
        return this.xBlackIcon;
    }

    public void setxDarkIcon(boolean xDarkIcon)
    {
        this.xBlackIcon = xDarkIcon;
    }

    public Color getBotonColor()
    {
        return this.button.getBackground();
    }

    public void setBotonColor(Color botonColor)
    {
        this.button.setBackground(botonColor);
        setSelectionColor(this.button.getBackground());
    }

    public Color getBorderColorFocus()
    {
        return this.borderColorFocus;
    }

    public void setBorderColorFocus(Color borderColorFocus)
    {
        this.borderColorFocus = borderColorFocus;
    }

    public Color getBorderColorNoFocus()
    {
        return this.borderColorNoFocus;
    }

    public void setBorderColorNoFocus(Color borderColorNoFocus)
    {
        this.borderColorNoFocus = borderColorNoFocus;
    }

    public boolean isMaterialMode()
    {
        return this.materialMode;
    }

    public void setMaterialMode(boolean materialMode)
    {
        this.materialMode = materialMode;
    }

    private void updateBorder()
    {
        Border border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 2, 0, this.borderColorFocus);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, 
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, this.button.getSize().width + 5)));
    }

    private void updateButton()
    {
        this.btnHeight = (getSize().height - 10);
        this.button.setSize(new Dimension(this.btnHeight, this.btnHeight));
        this.button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.btnHeight, this.btnHeight));

        this.button.setLocation(getWidth() - this.button.getWidth() - 5, 5);
        updateBorder();
    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
    {
        updateButton();
    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {}

    public void setPlaceholder(String placeholder)
    {
        this.placeholder = placeholder;
    }

    public String getPlaceholder()
    {
        return this.placeholder;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (isMaterialMode())
        {
            if (isFocusOwner())
            {
                Border border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 2, 0, this.borderColorFocus);
                setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, 
                        BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, this.button.getSize().width + 5)));

                this.phColor = getForeground();
            }
            else
            {
                Border border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 2, 0, this.borderColorNoFocus);
                setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, 
                        BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, this.button.getSize().width + 5)));

                this.phColor = this.borderColorNoFocus;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Border border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 2, 0, this.borderColorFocus);
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, 
                    BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, this.button.getSize().width + 5)));
            this.phColor = getForeground();
        }

        g.setColor(new Color(this.phColor.getRed(), this.phColor.getGreen(), this.phColor.getBlue(), 90));

        g.drawString(this.band ? this.placeholder : "", 
        getMargin().left, 
        getSize().height / 2 + getFont().getSize() / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to remove all `setBorder(...)` calls from the `paintComponent()` method. `paintComponent` is only for painting.

Comment: You can set all your borders from the method `setMaterialMode`. Also you need to implement a [focus listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) when you need different borders for focused and unfocused states.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy I really appreciate that If you can give me a sample code

Answer (score 3):

I have reproduced your java code on my machine and debugged it.
I found out why your code causes High CPU.

You used the `setBorder()` method within your `paintComponent()` method and that's false, because if you look into the `setBorder()` method in your parents class, you will see that this method always calls `repaint()` if the border has been changed. (And that's quite normal)

So if you call in your **paint()** method something which calls **repaint()** then you will be in a endless loop.

```
paint() -> repaint() -> paint() -> repaint() -> paint().....
```

And in your code you used `setBorder` 3 times.

You can solve this problem if you outsource your `setBorder` code and call it from elsewhere.

Comment: I may be wrong, but doesn't the repaint calls post paint events rather than handling them immediately?